# What are the limitations(minuses) have binary serialization than XML, CSV, etc?

Tags: serialization, binary

What are the limitations(minuses) have binary serialization than XML, CSV, etc?
And can you explain?

Comment: First thing that comes in my mind is loss of readability. XML/CSV format can be read using simple ASCII text editor while binary serialization does not offer this facility

Comment: Why do you ask exactly? What do you have in mind? What kind and what volume of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix and the Web are (historically) favoring textual formats (XML, JSON, YAML, ...) and protocols (HTTP, SMTP, ...), because they are easier to debug (and to understand) since you can use textual tools and editors on them. Many library functions (e.g. `fscanf` and `fprintf` ...) are favoring textual formats.

And several tools are probably biased for textual files (whatever that means exactly). For instance, a textual file can probably be more efficiently managed under a version control system like `git` or `svn` etc... (and the  `diff` and `patch` utilities are expecting textual data, with newlines to separate lines).

A possible disadvantage of textual format is that it may take more CPU time to encode/decode, and more disk space. (However disk space is cheap, textual data is compressible, and the bottleneck is the real I/O).

If you want compatibility of your binary data across various processors or compilers (or systems), you should explicitly take care of it, using "neutral" data formats like XDR or ASN1 and serialization libraries (e.g. [s11n](http://s11n.net/)).

Comment: But how about technical side? I mean if I'll serialization some object on one PC with x86 architecture processor, can I deserialization this object on other PC with x64? Is it depends? Or serialization some object on C# and deserialization on JAVA? Because, how I think, should be different binary value.

Comment: I improved my answer; compatibility of binary format is not guaranteed. You have to work to get it.